# unable to place material icon vertical center

Tags: css, google-material-icons

Am trying to place `material icon` in center of circle i tried following method
tried adding `vertical-align:middle` and added `text-align:center`

but nothing work.

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/materialicons/v41/flUhRq6tzZclQEJ-Vdg-IuiaDsNc.woff2) format('woff2');
}

.mi {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: 1;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  word-wrap: normal;
  direction: ltr;
  -webkit-font-feature-settings: 'liga';
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

a {
  border: 1px solid #3D3E02;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #334048;
}

a i {
  font-size: 20px;
}
.t{vertical-align:middle}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<br><br><br>
<a href="#"><i class="mi">&#xe0be;</i></a>
<br><br><br>
<a href="#"><i class="mi t">&#xe0be;</i></a>
```

Comment: The second one is working for me...what is the issue?

Comment: @Paulie_D the second one is slightly lean towards the bottom.! or is it only for me.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use     `display: inline-flex;` to `a`

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/materialicons/v41/flUhRq6tzZclQEJ-Vdg-IuiaDsNc.woff2) format('woff2');
}

.mi {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: 1;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  word-wrap: normal;
  direction: ltr;
  -webkit-font-feature-settings: 'liga';
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

a {
  display: inline-flex;
  border: 1px solid #3D3E02;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #334048;
}

a i {
  font-size: 20px;
}
.t{vertical-align:middle}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<br><br><br>
<a href="#"><i class="mi">&#xe0be;</i></a>
<br><br><br>
<a href="#"><i class="mi t">&#xe0be;</i></a>
```

Comment: that what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

I have changed the `.t{vertical-align:middle}` to `.t{vertical-align:bottom}` and it worked fine for me.

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/materialicons/v41/flUhRq6tzZclQEJ-Vdg-IuiaDsNc.woff2) format('woff2');
}

.mi {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: 1;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  word-wrap: normal;
  direction: ltr;
  -webkit-font-feature-settings: 'liga';
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

a {
  border: 1px solid #3D3E02;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #334048;
}

a i {
  font-size: 20px;
}
.t{vertical-align:bottom}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<br><br><br>
<a href="#"><i class="mi">&#xe0be;</i></a>
<br><br><br>
<a href="#"><i class="mi t">&#xe0be;</i></a>
```

Is this you are looking for.? Hope this solved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Change the styles:

from:

```
a {
  border: 1px solid #3D3E02;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #334048;
}
```

to

```
a{
}
```

from

```
a i {
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

to

```
a i {
    font-size: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #3D3E02;
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding: 10px;
}
```